# Multinomial expansion in non commutative ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics

Is there any formula for multinomial expansion in non commutative ring.
My problem is as follows

> I want to find a formula for $(x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_k)^n$ where the rule is $x_jx_i=q^{n_{ij}}x_ix_j$ for $i<j$, $n,k$ are positive integers and $q$ is an integer?

Answer (score 3):

In a general noncommutative ring, the only formula for that power is the sum of all the noncomutative monomials: indeed, it is clear that in a free algebra that is as good as it can get.

Now, if you do have the commutatitivity relations $$x_ix_j=q^{n_{i,j}}x_ix_j$$ whenever $1\leq i<j\leq k$, then more can be said. For example, suppose that $k=2$ and let us write the variables $x$ and $y$ and $yx=qxy$. I claim that there are polynomials $f_{n,i}(q)$ in the variable $q$, one for each $n\geq0$ and each $m$ with $0\leq m\leq n$, such that $$(x+y)^n=\sum_{i=0}^nf_{n,i}(q)x^iy^{n-i}.$$ Indeed, this is obvious if $n=0$, for then we need only pick $f_{0,0}(q)=1$. We can observe that 
\begin{align}
(x+y)^{n+1}
&=(x+y)(x+y)^n\\
&=(x+y)\sum_{i=0}^nf_{n,i}(q)x^iy^{n-i}\\
&=x\sum_{i=0}^nf_{n,i}(q)x^iy^{n-i}+y\sum_{i=0}^nf_{n,i}(q)x^iy^{n-i}\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^nf_{n,i}(q)x^{i+1}y^{n-i}+\sum_{i=0}^nf_{n,i}(q)yx^iy^{n-i}\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^nf_{n,i}(q)x^{i+1}y^{n-i}+\sum_{i=0}^nf_{n,i}(q)q^ix^iy^{n-i+1}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}f_{n,i-1}(q)x^{i}y^{n+1-i}+\sum_{i=0}^nf_{n,i}(q)q^ix^iy^{n-i+1}\\
&=f_{n,0}(q)y^{n+1}+\sum_{i=1}^n(f_{n,i-1}(q)+q^if_{n,i}(q))x^iy^{n+1-i}+f_{n,n}(q)x^{n+1}
\end{align}
and then we can choose 
\begin{align}
&f_{n+1,0}(q)=f_{n,0}(q), \\
&f_{n+1,i}(q)=f_{n,i-1}(q)+q^if_{n,i}(q) \qquad\text{if $1l\leq i\leq n$}, \\
&f_{n+1,n+1}(q)=f_{n,n}(q).
\end{align}
It is not difficult to show that these relations completely determine a family of polynomials.

Now, there is a well known family of polynomials, which is usually denoted $\binom{n}{m}_q$, one for each $n\geq0$ and each $m$ with $0\leq m\leq n$, called the Gaussian polynomials. These satisfy exactly the same recursion, and the same initial conditions, so we can immediately conclude that $f_{n,i}(q)=\binom{n}{i}_q$, that is, that $$(x+y)^n=\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{n}{m}_qx^iy^{n-i}.$$

You should Google for more information on these polynomials —they are very important, so you'll find lots of information. Let me just say that if for each $n\geq0$ we consider the polynomial $$[n]_q=1+q+q^2+\cdots+q^{n-1}$$ and the product $$[n]_q!=[1]_q[2]_q\cdots[n]_q,$$ then we have $$\binom{n}{m}_q=\frac{[n]_q!}{[m]_q![n-m]_q!}$$ for all $n\geq0$ and all $m$ such that $0\leq m\leq n$. Indeed, it is not difficult to show that these rational functions satisfy the relations above (and that impies, by induction, that they are in fact polynomials and not only rational functions)

Comment: If $k$ is larger than $2$, then similar results can be obtained, involving $q$-multinomial coefficients. Since everything is more cumbersome in the general case, I think that the best is to leave the details of that to the reader :-)

Comment: is there a recurssive relation possible in the genral case